# How to load an update in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, download

I'm working on an iPhone app with inApp payment: whenever the user pays a small sum, he receives an update of the application. The "update" is a sort of new "chapter" in an adventure game and it is made of text and xml files, images, sounds and so on, generically "assets". When the assets are downloaded, they form the content of a new chapter (or stage, or step) inside the application.

I'm looking for advices on how to load all this data: for example, the device, while downloading, could accidentally stop working (low battery, etc.) or it could disconnect for some reason. This way, the integrity of the update would be lost. I researched a little and found solutions with md5 checksum or sockets, but I wanted to ask here too, before starting anything. For example, I wanted to know if it is a good idea to download a big zip file or it would be better to download small uncompressed files.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup, and what I do is maintain a database of items installed.  I also have a separate list of items available which is updated from my server periodically.

When the user buys one, the item is copied from the "available" list to the "installed" list with a status of "purchased".  It then goes into a download queue.

After it's downloaded, the status is moved to "downloaded" and some installation is done.  Then the status is finally updated to "installed".

I protect against interruptions by having the app check when it starts (or is unbackgrounded) for any items in the "installed" list that don't have a status of "installed".  And depending on the status, I either restart the download or redo the installation.

As for file integrity, I just check for a known header, but an md5 or other checksum would be better.

**Update:** My app only downloads a single file (sqlite database), so if it gets interrupted it has to start over from the beginning.  I enabled deflate on my web server, which NSURLConnection supports, so compression is done transparently.  But I'm sure your interest in using a zip file is primarily to make downloading simpler.  I had considered using a zip file at one point too, but I was unable to find an easy way to extract it.

Comment: that's interesting. A couple of questions: when you start downloading, do you have a sort of flag (eg in a text file or db) that records the state of the app? I say this because, if I close accidentally my iPhone, when I restart the iPhone and launch the app, I probably want to start downloading again (and if nothing tells me I was downloading, how will I start again?). Another thing: are temporary disconnections something to deal with?

Comment: I depend on the list of installed items to see if any are incomplete.  I check this whenever the app resumes.  And if the connection gets terminated in any way, I start the download over.  HTTP supports resuming downloads but I didn't want to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put all the resources the game used when publish the game, and some chapters are locked, when user buy chapter through in App Purchase, you unlock the chapter.
So when user buy chapters, user don't need to download any files.

Comment: No, this is not an option because the content of the chapters is added by third parties and can change any time. Thanks for the gentle reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you could do is this: when they pay, they buy the right to install the next part of the application. That doesn't mean that it will install automatically.

What you should do is have the downloads on a list inside the app so that whenever they access this list, the app uses the wifi connection to test wether they have the right to install this part of the app. If so, the program checks for an existing installation, or you could just re-write the file or whatever.

For example:

[image]

The locks show that the user has not payed for these yet. If this image was in your app, before it is loaded, it would check a database or something from your computer to check if the user has purchased that stage yet, and if so return Yes or Nay.

Whenever you click on a button, it doesn't play the stage, it actually downloads the file. So naming it stage on my part was bad, it should be named "Download stage 1" or something like that.

---

Edit:
This depends entirely on the app, the size of the files, etc. In most cases I would just have uncompressed files to make it easier on the user, but if they are very large files, you should use compressed files. I've never used compressed files personally, but I think that having to extract the files in the iphone would pose a problem for some users.

Comment: I must have written something wrong in the question. I don't want to know how to organize the entire app. I want to know which is the best way to execute the download of the files.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns revised answer